# Copying a war file from GitLab to EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I am trying to create a CI/CD pipeline to build war file and deploy it to EC2 from GitLab.

Once the war file is created, I would like to copy it to some folder in EC2 so that from there I would like to copy it to tomcat server.

The following is the ".gitlab-ci.yml" file.

```yaml
stages:
    - build
    - deploy

build:
    stage: build
    image: maven:3-jdk-8
    script:
        - mvn install
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - target/

deploy:
    stage: deploy

    before_script:
        # Generate SSH Key
        - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
        - echo -e "$EC2_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
    script:
        - scp target/gitlabec2pipeline.war ec2-user@$EC2_DEPLOY_SERVER:/gitlabec2pipeline.war
        - bash .gitlab-deploy-ec2.sh
```

I have added the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_KEY variables.
But when the above pipeline is run, in the deploy stage the scp command is giving "permission denied" error.
Any idea on how to solve this?

Error Message:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.5.2 (e91107dd)
  on blue-3.shared.runners-manager.gitlab.com/default zxwgkjAP
Resolving secrets
00:00
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor
Using Docker executor with image ruby:2.5 ...
Pulling docker image ruby:2.5 ...
Using docker image sha256:27d049ce98db4e55ddfaec6cd98c7c9cfd195bc7e994493776959db33522383b for ruby:2.5 with digest ruby@sha256:ecc3e4f5da13d881a415c9692bb52d2b85b090f38f4ad99ae94f932b3598444b ...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on runner-zxwgkjap-project-31676452-concurrent-0 via runner-zxwgkjap-shared-1639429231-955193ca...
Getting source from Git repository
00:02
$ eval "$CI_PRE_CLONE_SCRIPT"
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/te2122/deploytoaws/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out dc27fd6f as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Downloading artifacts
00:02
Downloading artifacts for build (1880203000)...
Downloading artifacts from coordinator... ok        id=1880203000 responseStatus=200 OK token=9RSALYus
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:02
Using docker image sha256:27d049ce98db4e55ddfaec6cd98c7c9cfd195bc7e994493776959db33522383b for ruby:2.5 with digest ruby@sha256:ecc3e4f5da13d881a415c9692bb52d2b85b090f38f4ad99ae94f932b3598444b ...
$ mkdir -p ~/.ssh
$ echo -e "$EC2_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
$ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
$ [[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
$ scp target/gitlabec2pipeline.war ec2-user@$EC2_DEPLOY_SERVER:/gitlabec2pipeline.war
Warning: Permanently added '54.205.169.131' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
scp: /gitlabec2pipeline.war: Permission denied
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide the **exact** permission denied error you are seeing?

Comment: Added the deploy job log. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

> I have added the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_KEY variables.

AWS keys don't matter here since you're using SSH key for authentication when you use ssh (or `scp`) to connect to the EC2 instance.

If you are sure you're using the correct key value, your environment variable `$EC2_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` is not well-formed. Common issues come up with newlines in the variable and use of CRLF (often can be added when copy/pasting the key in the web UI) instead of LF.

To work around this more reliably, you could:

1. use a [file type variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#cicd-variable-types), then copy the file into `~/.ssh` OR
2. base64 encode your key before putting it into the CI variable. This avoids any possible issues with newlines and CRLF. Then decode it in the job, placing the value into the file.

Update:

It looks like your user does not have permission to the destination directory on the server. You need to either give appropriate permission to the `ec2-user` or choose a different destination location where the user does have permission to write files.

Comment: I tried with file type variable. But no luck. One thing I observed is "echo -e "$EC2_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa" is not creating id_rsa file. Any mistake I am doing?

Comment: @Subbu thanks for updating the question. It looks like your `ec2-user` on the instance doesn't have permission to write files to the root `/`.  Try putting the file somewhere else where the user has permission.